# JMonkeyEngine advice for networking support

Tags: android, game-engine, jmonkeyengine

Can I use http://jmonkeyengine.org/groups/android/forum/topic/how-to-get-started-1/ to build a 2d multiplayer card game for Android?

Actually I only need its networking/multiplayer support.

Any advice on this?